# Use each to show array data with comma separartor

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax

I have this code and run properly with static data :

```
$('#jqChart').jqChart({
    title: { text: 'Gantt Chart' },
    animation: { duration: 1 },
    legend: {
        visible: false
    },

    series: [
        {
            type: 'gantt',
            fillStyles: ["#418CF0", "#FCB441", "#E0400A", "#056492", "#BFBFBF"],
            data: [
               ['Phase 1', new Date(1394, 06, 01), new Date(1394, 09, 20), 'Task 1'],
               ['Phase 1', new Date(1394, 06, 01), new Date(1394, 09, 20), 'Task 1']
               //$(wfs).each(function (ix, wf) {
               //    ['Phase 2', new Date(1396, 06, 01), new Date(1396, 06, 01), 'Task 2'] +','
               //})
            ],
            labels: {
                fillStyle: 'white'
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

And i want to pass my data with each , when i used my code without `Comma` , the desired output will not show.

Here's my final code that was not run properly :

```
$('#jqChart').jqChart({
    title: { text: 'Gantt Chart' },
    animation: { duration: 1 },
    legend: {
        visible: false
    },

    series: [
        {
            type: 'gantt',
            fillStyles: ["#418CF0", "#FCB441", "#E0400A", "#056492", "#BFBFBF"],
            data: [
               //['Phase 1', new Date(1394, 06, 01), new Date(1394, 09, 20), 'Task 1'],
               //['Phase 1', new Date(1394, 06, 01), new Date(1394, 09, 20), 'Task 1']
               $(wfs).each(function (ix, wf) {
                   ['Phase 2', new Date(1396, 06, 01), new Date(1396, 06, 01), 'Task 2'] + ','
                   ['Phase 2', new Date(1396, 06, 01), new Date(1396, 06, 01), 'Task 2'] 
               })
            ],
            labels: {
                fillStyle: 'white'
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Could you let us know what `$(wfs)` evaluates to?

Comment: wfs is our array that read from response.d

Comment: var gc = response.d;;
var wfs = gc.awfs;

Comment: I meant, what value does `wfs` have? Please add at least a representative example to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run functions inside an array constructor. Create the array before you initialize the plugin and pass the array reference to the config

```
var chartData = [];

$.each(wfs,function(ix, wf) {
  chartData.push(['Phase from wf', date1FromWf, date2FromWf, 'Task from wf']);
});

$('#jqChart').jqChart({
  title: {
    text: 'Gantt Chart'
  },
  animation: {
    duration: 1
  },
  legend: {
    visible: false
  },

  series: [{
    type: 'gantt',
    fillStyles: ["#418CF0", "#FCB441", "#E0400A", "#056492", "#BFBFBF"],
    data: chartData,// array from above
    labels: {
      fillStyle: 'white'
    }
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that "wfs is our array that read from response.d" then you could just use `wfs` as is, assuming it contains the appropriate data.

Assuming `wfs` looks something like

```
[
    ['Phase 2', new Date(1396, 06, 01), new Date(1396, 06, 01), 'Task 2'],
    ['Phase 2', new Date(1396, 06, 01), new Date(1396, 06, 01), 'Task 2']
]
```

Then you can just use it inline:

```
$('#jqChart').jqChart({
    title: { text: 'Gantt Chart' },
    animation: { duration: 1 },
    legend: {
        visible: false
    },

    series: [
        {
            type: 'gantt',
            fillStyles: ["#418CF0", "#FCB441", "#E0400A", "#056492", "#BFBFBF"],
            data: wfs, // use wfs inline
            labels: {
                fillStyle: 'white'
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

I don't think `jQuery.each()` does what you think it does.

Comment: No way it will contain date objects. Has to be modified in loop and `each` works fine as loop